# Get Bluetooth ATT Characteristic UUID from Handle in Packet Capture

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm reversing the protocol used by my treadmill to try and make a less terrible app.

I think I have the gist of the protocol worked out from some packet captures:

## Sending Commands

UUID: `2AD9` (Fitness Machine Control Point)

ATT OPCODE: `0x012` (Write Request)

| Operation | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Start | `00` |
| Stop | `08 01` |
| Set Speed | `02 XX XX` |

`XX XX` is Speed in 100 x kmh

## Receiving Data

UUID: `2ACD` (Treadmill Data)

ATT OPCODE: `0x1b` (Received Handle Value Notification)

| `84 24` | `XX XX` | `XX XX` | `XX XX` | `00 ff` | `ff ff` | `XX XX` | `XX XX` | `00` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Start | Speed | Metres | Calories | ? | ? | Seconds | Steps | END |

And this *was* working when I sent requests through nRF Connect to it the other night. This is actually how I got the UUIDs, I just spammed each endpoint with 0 bytes until the treadmill started. However, now it's not and I'm not entirely sure why.

So, taking a look back through the packet captures, I see this sequence of writes as soon as the app connects before it does anything:

[image: Packet Capture]

So, I'm thinking this is some sort of setup/handshake that I'm missing and somehow must have still been present on the treadmill from an app run when I was messing with it the other night.

Now, I'm using [this MAUI lib](https://github.com/dotnet-bluetooth-le/dotnet-bluetooth-le) to connect to the treadmill and read its characteristics.

Unfortunately, it just gives me UUIDs for each of the characteristics, which I can't work out how to tie back to the handles in the packet capture so that I can try and replay the handshake and see if that is my problem.

Is there a way to do this or am I going to have to step through each characteristic, send a request, and then capture that and try and map the two together manually?

FWIW, these handles seem consistent between captures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that this is simply not possible in userspace and would require interacting with the bluetooth controller at a much lower level.

To solve this I ended up doing the following on my laptop:

1. Start capturing packets
2. Using nRF connect, connect to the treadmill
3. Find the characteristics I wanted in nRF connect listed by UUID
4. Send a single packet to that UUID
5. Observe the handle in the packet capture
6. Repeat until I'd found all the ones I wanted

This was probably easier than my initial thought of programattically hitting them all and then trying to pair them up after from a complete log but it's still not ideal.